# How to get the json value from postman input by the python code?

Tags: python, json, api, postman, cgi

I'am trying to create a API with normal python without using
any framework. This is my API login page code:

```
    #!C:\python39\python.exe
    import cgi
    from config import opp
    import json
    
    print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
    
    z = opp()
    jsonval = json.loads(jsonobg)
    
    
    z.email = jsonval['email']
    z.password = jsonval['password']
    
    if z.email != "" and z.password != "":
        if not z.login():
            print(json.dumps({"status":200, "title":"success", 
    "message":"loggedin successfully"}))
        else:
            print(json.dumps({"status":400, "title":"error", 
    "message":"the user does not extists"}))
    else:
        print(json.dumps({"status":400, "title":"error", 
    "message":"you cannot leave the field empty"}))
```

here I get the connection and login function from the config page. I am using xampp to run this simple api. every thing is working properly. but, if I try to run it in postman software, I don't know how to get the email and password from the postman input and give it to the jsonobj variable to put it in the json.load function. we will give the postman input like '{"email":"example@gmail.com", "password":"pass123"}' but I don't know how to transfer this data to python code. please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it, maybe if you give details about what is `jsonobg`, `opp`, and what exactly you want from postman, maybe would be better to help you out!

Comment: This looks like incomplete code, which makes it hard for us to debug. What is `jsonobg`? What is `config`? Can you show your sample Postman request? Does it work in Postman right now?